# Regular expression to select text across multiple lines

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to select text between two curly braces in a Java file. Text between braces may be spread across multiple lines.

Eg.,

```
{
   // line1 ;
   // line 2 ;
   // line 3 ;
}
```

I need to select all the lines in between braces.

I tried `\{[.]*\}` but it doesn't select multiple lines.

Please suggest me in this regard. 
Thanks.

Comment: you can try this `{[^}]*}`

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this  is not a good idea as you need to take nested brackets, etc. into account. You might be better off using a parser instead.
This being said, you might get along with the following construct:

```
^\{
(.+?)
^\}
```

This assumes, that your opening and closing brackets stand alone in one line. If you want to allow whitespaces as well, you'll need to alter it to:

```
^\s*\{
(.+?)
^\s*\}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XQXayr/1) (and mind the different modifiers, ie `DOTALL` and `MULTILINE` !).

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to verify this particular regex in any of my editors Atom, Eclipse, Vim :( I can see it working only in regex101.com. Seems many of the editors do not support or partially support expression flags.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add line breaks in the regular expression... Try this:
    \{(.*\r\n)*\}

Comment: Simply: no. You need to escape the brackets in most regex flavors, additionally, this will only work for one line (unless `DOTALL` is specified).

Comment: Yes, brackets needs to be escaped. I had put the escape character but I guess it got removed.  I have edited it. To print escape character I had to put another escape character.

Comment: Moreover, it works even if there are multiple lines in between the curly braces. You may need to remove carriage return (\r) accordingly.